# Runtime creation of Delphi Firemonkey components from a string

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, rtti

How can i create at runtime a visual component as a child of the form using eventually RTTI?
All i got is a TValue instance...

```
 t := (ctx.FindType(Edit1.Text) as TRttiInstanceType);
 inst:= t.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(t.MetaclassType,[Form1]);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A purely RTTI approach using `TRttiMethod.Invoke()` would look something like this:

```
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  t: TRttiInstanceType;
  m: TRttiMethod;
  params: TArray<TRttiParameter>;
  v: TValue;
  inst: TControl;
begin
  t := ctx.FindType(Edit1.Text) as TRttiInstanceType;
  if t = nil then Exit;
  if not t.MetaclassType.InheritsFrom(TControl) then Exit;
  for m in t.GetMethods('Create') do
  begin
    if not m.IsConstructor then Continue;
    params := m.GetParameters;
    if Length(params) <> 1 then Continue;
    if params[0].ParamType.Handle <> TypeInfo(TComponent) then Continue;
    v := m.Invoke(t.MetaclassType, [TComponent(Form1)]);
    inst := v.AsType<TControl>();
    // or: inst := TControl(v.AsObject);
    Break;
  end;
  inst.Parent := ...;
  ...
end;
```

A much simpler approach that does not use `TRttiMethod.Invoke()` would look like this:

```
type
  // TControlClass is defined in VCL, but not in FMX
  TControlClass = class of TControl;

var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  t: TRttiInstanceType;
  inst: TControl;
begin
  t := ctx.FindType(Edit1.Text) as TRttiInstanceType;
  if t = nil then Exit;
  if not t.MetaclassType.InheritsFrom(TControl) then Exit;
  inst := TControlClass(t.MetaclassType).Create(Form4);
  inst.Parent := ...;
  //...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick but what if i need to set Text property of the control?

Comment: `Text` is a public property of `TTextControl`, which derives from `TControl`. So either type-cast `inst` to `TTextControl` to access `Text` directly, or use RTTI to get the `TRttiProperty` for `Text` and then call `TRttiProperty.SetValue()`.

Comment: Ok! I will go with first option! Thanks!